# VRaptor - using Query Parameters

Tags: java, query-string, vraptor

Is there a possibility to use something like `@QueryParam` (or `@Context`) using `VRaptor 3`?
I really like the `include/exclude` `json` or `representation` features of the framework. That will be meaningless if there is no possibility to pass the elemnts to include/exclude.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I catch the idea, can you elaborate? But the fact is that there is

nothing like `@Context` (assuming that you're talking about JAX-RS). You can see about

the way VRaptor does param binding here: http://www.vraptor.org/en/docs/controllers-rest/